# Перенаправление пользователя на другую страницу при ошибке.

Tags: glassfish, java

Здравствуйте.
Как при ошибке сервера, когда пользователю на страницу выдается такого рода ошибка
[image]

выводить пользователю свою *собственную*, другую страницу. Причем при ошибках какого-то определенного рода, - *одну* страницу; а при ошибках другого рода - *другую*. И как отлавливать такие исключительные ситуации, чтобы *перенаправить* пользователя на другую страницу?
Больше всего интересует, как отлавливать ошибки, когда сессия на сервере была уничтожена.

Использую **JSF 2.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартную страницу ошибки можно прописать в web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Если речь идёт о какой-то конкретной ошибке, то вы можете использовать Servlet Filter ([пример](http://www.java2ee.ru/servlets/filters.html)), в котором сможете проверять, есть ли у пользователя сессия или нет. И если нет, то слать redirect на любую вашу страницу.

Что-то наподобие этого:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter { 
   // ...
   public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                                                   ServletException { 
          if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
              response.sendRedirect("/errors/my-error-page");
              return;
          }
          chain.doFilter(request, response); 
   } 
   //...........................
}
```

**UPD**

Если вы хотите отловить какое-то конкретное исключение, которое может выпасть на вашей странице, то вы можете обернуть строку chain.doFilter(request, response);  в блок try/catch и в catch попытаться что-то предпринять.

Comment: Ух-ты как красиво можно сделать! СПАСИБО )))

Comment: Разумеется, может оказаться, что потребуется более сложная проверка, нежели request.getSession(false). Но это уже на ваше усмотрение ;)

Comment: Ну это само собой. Главное, что нашел способ, как сессию проверять и что в ней находится. А дальше извращаться как угодно можно.